# What is the best method to create a animation in UIImageView using PNG frames without using much memory

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I want to play an animation in my mainView ( Company Logo ) . I am using sequence of PNG images  . I have more than 500 frames . What is the best method to create a animation in UIImageView using PNG frmaes without using much memory......

My animation is a small header logo in this size

```
GRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150);
```

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112698/how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios/8113027#8113027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you have so many frames, the best thing to do is to convert the animation to a video, and show that one?